# PHP - Post getting lost after 70th variable in the array

Tags: arrays, post, php

Okay, I've spent way to long trying to figure this out. I have a while loop that takes rows from a database and echos an input for each one with `selected_id[]` for the names. On submit I use $_REQUEST to collect the selected checkboxes, but for some reason, none of the inputs after the 70th variable will post. `selected_id[0]` through `selected_id[70]` will post just like normal but `selected_id[71]` and higher will not.

Why am I only able to $_REQUEST an array up to the 70th variable in that array??

If I remove one of the entries from the database, then the problem will still occur at the 71st entry echoed or `selected_id[70]`

I'm using PHP Version 5.3.15 and my max_input_vars is set to 1000. my max_input_nesting_level is set to 64, but I don't believe that is whats causing the problem. My memory_limit is set to 20M.

Here is the majority my code:

```
<?php


   if(!empty($_REQUEST[assignedprocess])){

    $selected_id = $_REQUEST[selected_id];
    $howmany = count($selected_id);
    $msgback="(".$howmany.") Entry(ies) updated. <br>";
      echo $msgback; 
   }

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post" name="index">

    <?php

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_groups)){

        echo "<input name="selected_id[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row[id].'" />";

        }

    ?>
<input type="hidden" name="assignedprocess" value="11">
<input type="submit" name="subs" value="Apply">  
</form>
```

Sorry for my sloppy code and horrible English... I really appreciate any help you can give, thanks in advance.

Comment: I Think you miss a echo in the print of the html lines in the while loop!

Comment: off topic, but please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and no longer being maintained. If possible, it would be a good idea to switch to either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libs.

Answer (score 1):

**Set php_value post_max_size to be 15M(or more) in the php.ini:**

```
php_value post_max_size 15M
```

**Fix code:(You miss echo function)**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="index">

    <?php

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_groups)){
          $id= $row[id];
          echo  "<input name='selected_id[]' type='checkbox' value= $id />";



        }

    ?>
<input type="hidden" name="assignedprocess" value="11">
<input type="submit" name="subs" value="Apply">  
</form>
```

Comment: Well my post_max_size is set to 100M in my WHM PHP Configuration, and even when I check my info.php on that specific website, it says my post_max_size is set to 100M. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the length of you're post is larger than what PHP has been configured for.

If you're on shared hosting, you can use .htaccess, like so:

```
#set max post size
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Otherwise, edit the php.ini if you have you're own server...

Size to use... up-to-you, 20M is a good size as a starter.

Comment: post_max_size is set to 100M, but I'll add to my htaccess and see if that will fix. Thanks