# Cannot post hidden input after update PHP 5.3.8 to PHP 5.3.24

Tags: php, post, input, hidden

I upgrade my PHP v5.3.8 to v5.3.24.
Since updating my script no longer works.

An input variable POST it's the problem.

Form source code here : http://pastebin.com/N4XKSQjR

The line problem is the following (last line):

```
<input type="hidden" name="count_result" value="416">
```

On my PHP processing form page (traitement.php) i recover this field like this:

```
 $count_result = $_POST['count_result'];
```

And i get this php error :

> Notice: Undefined index count_result on line...

The script works without problems with PHP 5.3.8 but not with PHP 5.3.24.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: link of pastbeans looks dead could you update ?

Comment: are us checking isset($_POST ?

Comment: Do the rest of your hidden fields work ok?

Comment: Pastebin works for me... isset($_POST['count_number']) return false. I get the first hidden fields correctly without problems. Just last  hidden input is the problem.

Comment: It really _shouldn't_ matter, but have you tried it with moving that `hidden` field to the top with the others?

Comment: Yes if I move the last hidden input `'count_result'` to top of the form with the other fields it works only the last hidden field `'count_result'` is a variable counted with PHP so I can not move higher in the code. Apparently it seems that we can not put hidden  input fields after input fields stored in an array NB_SAI_SOI[]...

Comment: Create the HTML in a variable and put the, and then append it to the beginning for the form you create near the end (ie, create everything but the `<form...><hidden count_result`, etc and then create that part as a variable at the end and add the HTML to it.  (Or use a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) ^^ )

Comment: I have several applications that use this system it means that I have to update all my other applications after updating PHP 5.3.24 ?

Comment: It's kind of odd - I've never ran in to this problem before.  Have you done a `var_dump($_POST);` with it in both positions as well (maybe to see exactly when variables get cut off/etc?  Did you also upgrade apache/iss/etc?  (And, out of curiosity, why didn't you make the upgrade to PHP 5.4 instead?).  Please use `@jon` so I get a notification when you respond as others have posted comments here as well =]

Comment: have any js remove or change the "count_result" tag or form post or get

Comment: @Jon `var_dump($_POST)` return correctly all variable except 'count_result' (count_result does not appear). I updated PHP 5.3.24 because PHP 5.4 requires many changes in source code. My apache version is 2.2.21.

Comment: I am sorry.  It is peculiar.  Is it the same for all tested browsers?  Is there javascript involved in there somewhere?  Other than that, I haven't a clue - can't find any bug reports or similar.  Do you have a browser plugin that allows you to view what is being sent or anything of the sort?  The only thing other than those I can think of would be an issue like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960444/php-post-getting-lost-after-70th-variable-in-the-array as the `post_max_size` is something that could have changed in the upgrade.

Comment: @Jon Yes I know it is especially as a problem lol
I tried using PHP 5.4.14 and the problem persists.
I do not think that the `post_max_size` is the problem because I get the php.ini file from my old PHP 5.3.8 version into PHP version 5.3.24. There are no JS I also tried with just the HTML code that I provided to you is the pastebin and exactly the same problem occurs.

Comment: Found the problem! (Turning on warnings would have helped you immensely ;) )

Comment: @Jon Yes that's work with `max_input_vars = 10000` but there are less than 1000 input variable no ? Why i don't have the same error like you so ? `Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.` My error_reporting is : `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Comment: Maybe try removing the `E_STRICT`, not sure why it's `OR`'d with `E_ALL` but that might be causing it to not choose all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I've been able to find, and based on the error I get while trying to duplicate the problem.  Note, I tested this on PHP 5.4.x
The error:

> Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000

In my `php.ini` the line:

```
; max_input_vars = 1000
```

has been commented out - meaning it was defaulting to `1000`.  [Prior to 5.3.9](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php), **this was not an option**, therefore you didn't encounter the problem and it was unlimited ^^.  With PHP >=5.3.9 it defaults to `1000`, so to make your script compatible with so many inputs, you need to set that directive in PHP.  I set it to 2000 and it worked perfectly.

Since you copied your old php.ini, it probably won't exist in there, so add:

```
max_input_vars = 2000
```

somewhere in there and it will at least work for your current example. ^^

Comment: Yes that's work with `max_input_vars = 2000` but there are less than 1000 input variable no ? 

Why i don't have the same error like you so ?

My error_reporting is : `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Comment: That is interesting.  Not sure why you didn't get that error then. O.o  Each of your arrays you make in HTML have 51 entries.  Each of those 51 counts towards the limit as well, so, for example `ACT_CODE` counts as 51 inputs towards that limit. ^^