# PHP E_WARNING Input variables exceeded not displayed

Tags: php, post, warnings

I have a problem with my PHP 5.3.24.
My PHP not display E_WARNING message in my script.

I want to appear the following error:

> Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000

In my setup this error does not appear when it should appear.
Here my php.ini file: http://pastebin.com/iC7yQ2bm

Follows the following discussion : [Cannot post hidden input after update PHP 5.3.8 to PHP 5.3.24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165713/cannot-post-hidden-input-after-update-php-5-3-8-to-php-5-3-24)

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you sure you don't override settings in your php file? I see you set good value in your php.ini try to put error_reporting(E_ALL); just before line you expect to give error

Comment: My php file : `<?php
$count_result = $_POST['count_result'];
var_dump($count_result, $_POST); 
?>`

Comment: What's your OS? At least on my Ubuntu installation, I had the same issue due to an error in the ini file

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 (Apache 2.2.21)

Comment: @barbuslex Your php.ini file looks good - I mean no errors. But did you restart your web server after making changes? If not, do so now and re-test.

Comment: @itsols Yes i restart apache services between each change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors

in your php.ini / htaccess

```
display_startup_errors = On
```

or you may need more...

```
error_reporting = -1
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

sadly you can't do nothing more than print or not to print it

Comment: Not working too. My .htaccess file: `php_value max_input_vars 1
php_flag display_startup_errors On
php_value error_reporting -1
php_flag display_errors On
php_flag display_startup_errors On`

Comment: probably you are not allowed to change these values from htaccess... run a phpinfo() and see if values are properly set

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the very first line of your php file

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

if it doesn't show errors it means there are none.

moreover, check -> http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: Not working. I set these lines in my traitement.php and i don't have the `Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000` but I do not get the 'count_result' post variable. (show this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165713/cannot-post-hidden-input-after-update-php-5-3-8-to-php-5-3-24)